# Cors-anywhere not working in chrome in production of Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, cors, httpclient, cors-anywhere

I've tried to use newsapi to build and host a website. I've used angular 6 and for hosting I've used firebase. When i get response using httpclient I was getting CORS issue which I've resolved using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com. It is working fine in all browsers except chrome. It's giving proper response in firefox, but not in chrome.

I'm getting the following error:

Yi {headers: Vi, status: 426, statusText: "Upgrade Required", url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://newsap…020-06-03&apiKey=*******************", ok: false, …}

error: {status: "error", code: "corsNotAllowed", message: "Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost."} headers: Vi {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ} message: "Http failure response for https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?pageSize=100&q=celebrity%20and%20sports&language=en&sortBy=relevancy&from=2020-06-03&apiKey=**********************: 426 Upgrade Required" name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 426 statusText: "Upgrade Required" url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that NewsApi made their service available ONLY for paying customers (...) everybody else gets access only through their localhost. Their free plan is called "Developer Plan" (find here: https://newsapi.org/pricing ). When your console says that "Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost", to the best of my knowledge, it means you would have to pay for their service now. I didn't because it is super expensive for a pet project. Let me know if you found a work-around it

Comment: If that's the case, the news response shouldn't come in other browsers. But in my case I can see responses in other browsers such as firefox, IE etc. So I couldn't figure out what is the issue.

Comment: @RaghuramBhooma Hey, that is good! May I take a look at your GitHub repo?

Comment: @RaghuramBhooma Any news (no pun intended)?